# Trouble connecting to db2

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I'm having trouble connecting to db2.
When I click 'Manage' -> 'Open console' in db2 main page, usually it connects me to the service.
But today I got the error message below.

---

{"trace":"a179b62aca4f14f933f1590ac4176eb0","errors":[{"code":"authentication_failure","message":"HWCSEC0016E: Authentication failed for SSO. This may caused by failed to generate access token in console side using existing credentials.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}

---

I'm fairly new to programming, so I don't have the faintest idea how to proceed from here.
Does anybody know what the problem is in this case and how can I fix it?

Comment: It may be caused by a problem inside IBM's cloud service. If you are using the free ('lite') plan then delete your service and recreate it in a different datacentre location.   If you are using a paid cloud service, then contact IBM support.   This is not a matter for Stackoverflow.

Comment: See also https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006XEYUl/db2-console-not-starting?language=en_US

Comment: @mao I'm using the lite plan. I deleted and recreated my service in a different location and it works fine. Thank you!!